Expectation and Conditional Probability
An urn contains $a$ white and $b$ black balls, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. One ball at a time is randomly drawn until the first white ball is drawn. find the expected number of black balls that are drawn, by considering conditional probabilities.
I can solve this using recurrence relation and induction to get the answer, i.e. $\frac{b}{a+1}$. However, I cannot think of an approach that uses conditional probabilities. Below is my approach.
Let $X_{a,b}$ denote the number of black balls drawn if we have $a$ white and $b$ black balls in the beginning. By conditional expectation,
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{a,b}) = \frac{b}{a+b}(1+\mathbb{E}(X_{a,b-1})).
$$
Solving the recurrence relation using induction, I get $\frac{b}{a+1}$. However, I will be very happy if anyone could share his/her approach using conditional probabilities. I have seen people posted similar questions previously, but not using a conditional probability approach.

But the conditional approach... is the one you're already taking? I'm confused about what you want that it doesn't already give you.

The simplest answer I am aware of is that without replacement, the probability a particular black ball is picked before all the white balls (i.e. before the first white ball) is $\frac{1}{a+1}$ so the expected number of black balls before the first white ball is $b$ times this by linearity of expectation, which is $\frac{b}{a+1}$. But this is not a conditional probability argument.

Let $X_{a,b}\ge 0$ be the number of black balls drawn by the time the first white one is drawn.
Let $B_1=\{$the first drawn ball is black$\}$.
Then
$$
\mathbb P(X_{a,b}=0)=\frac{a}{a+b}
$$
and for $k=1,2,\dots,b$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_{a,b}=k)&=\mathbb P(X_{a,b}=k\mid B_1)\mathbb P(B_1)
+\mathbb P(X_{a,b}=k\mid B_1^c)\mathbb P(B_1^c)
\\ &=\mathbb P(X_{a,b-1}=k-1)\times \frac{b}{a+b}
+0\times \frac{a}{a+b}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{a}{a+b}\right)\ \mathbb P(X_{a,b-1}=k-1).
\end{align}
By induction, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_{a,b}=k)&=\left(1-\frac{a}{a+b}\right)\left(1-\frac{a}{a+b-1}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{a}{a+b-(k-1)}\right)\times\frac{a}{a+b-k}
\\ &
=\frac{b!}{(b-k)!}\frac{(a+b-k)!}{(a+b)!}\frac{a}{a+b-k}
=\frac{b!a}{(a+b)!}\frac{(a+b-1-k)!}{(b-k)!}.
\end{align}
From this,
$$
\mathbb E X_{a,b}=\frac{b!a}{(a+b)!} \sum_{k=0}^b
k\frac{(a+b-1-k)!}{(b-k)!}
=\frac{b!a}{(a+b)!} \sum_{m=0}^b
(b-m)\frac{(a-1+m)!}{m!}
=\frac{b!a}{(a+b)!}
\frac{(a + b - 1)!(a + b)}{(b - 1)!a(a + 1) }=\frac{b}{a+1}.
$$
